# cy.get return invalid jquery element

Tags: jquery, chai, cypress

Here is a snip of my test code:

```js
cy.get('div[data-component-data-id=301602] h2:first')
  .should(($el) => {
    expect($el).to.have.text('dress')
  })
```

and cypress complains about the assertion:

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object.

The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:

  > text

The invalid subject you asserted on was:

  > Object{3}

To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.

This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.
```

So I have to change `expect($el).to.have.text('dress')` to `expect($el[0]).to.have.text('dress')`, then the complain dismissed and test passed.

I debug the assertion a bit, turns out `$el[0]` is also a jquery element.

Here is a snapshot about `$el` and `$el[0]`:

[image]

So my question is: **Isn't `cy.get` equivalent to jquery `$`? Why should I have to get the first element from `$el`? Why `$el[0] is also a jquery element?`**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that this error related to the application code when it includes zepto library. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6529) in the Cypress Github repository which you can track the progress.

Comment: See [.should(), Yields](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Yields) - ***some chainers change the subject***. Perhaps this is what's going on. Can you post the shape of `$el`?

Comment: @RichardMatsen I removed `.should('have.length', 1)` and print `$el` to the console, `$el` is `V [jQuery.fn.init(1), selector: ""]`, not a regular jquery object

Comment: @RichardMatsen I'm using Cypress v4.0.2, and I also tried v3.8.3, same error :-(

Comment: @RichardMatsen I raised an [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6529#issuecomment-590253657) in cypress repository, still waiting for response :-)

Comment: That's interesting, it does work with `expect($el)` when querying a simple page. I always use `$el[0]`. Will have to see if I can break any of my existing tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for at this stage, but have found a way to reset the effect of the zepto library.

To summarize,

- zepto is a jquery-compatible library that takes over the `$` global on your app window [ref](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/b5ed8d607f67724788ec9ff492be297f64d47dfc/src/zepto.js#L231)

  > $ = function(selector, context) {
  >   return zepto.init(selector, context)
  >   }
- the result is that cy commands like `.get()` and `.wrap()` yield a zepto-wrapped form of the jquery result that's not compatible with chai `expect()` without some destructuring.

Experimenting with `Cypress.$` I found this is still referencing jquery propper, for example

```
const h2 = Cypress.$('h2')
```

returns a jquery object not a zepto object, so we can reset the app global `$` from Cypress.$.

```js
it('title display', () => {

  cy.visit('index.html')  // zepto takes effect here

  // Reset $
  const win = cy.state('window');
  win.$ = Cypress.$;

  cy.get('h2')
    .should($el => {
      expect($el).to.have.text('dress')  // passes
    })
})
```

The reset code could be incorporated into an overwrite of the `cy.visit()` command to make it less pervasive.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  return originalFn(url, options).then(_ => {
    const win = cy.state('window')
    win.$ = Cypress.$
  })
})
...

it('title display', () => {

  cy.visit('index.html')

  cy.get('h2')
    .should($el => {
      expect($el).to.have.text('dress')  // passes
    })
})
```

**NOTE** This affects the way zepto works in the app.

---

**Work around that leaves Zepto functional**

This version of the `cy.visit()` overwrite will leave the Zepto library functional, but allow Cypress to `.should()` to receive the correct jQuery object.

Essentially we add our own proxy (on top of zepto's proxy) and examine the type of the selector on each call.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  return originalFn(url, options).then(_ => {
    const win = cy.state('window')
    const zepto_$ = win.$;
    win.$ = function(selector, context) {
      return typeof selector === 'string' 
        ? zepto_$(selector, context) 
        : Cypress.$(selector, context);
    }
  })
})
```

Use this html fragment to test it. If the two logs are identical, zepto is not affected.

```
<body>
  <h2>dress</h2>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    console.log('from app, call #1', $('h2'))
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('from app, call #2', $('h2'))
    }, 1000)
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. Reset `win.$` after `cy.visit` may still affect the application code, as there may be some async code that uses `$`.

Comment: Yes, that's my thought too. I tried doing a temporary reset within an overwrite of the `cy.get()` command, i.e reset $, perform the get, then set it back before taking any action on the app that may involve zepto. No luck with this so far.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like using `.and("contain", "dress")` would solve your issue.

## EDIT :

I've tried running a snippet similar to yours on my machine. Using `should` didn't seem to have the expected results and I encountered the same jquery weird behavior. However, when using `then`, it works like a charm. **$el and $el[0] both return the jquery element normally**

```js
cy.get("h1.h2:first").then(($el) => {
    cy.log($el)
    cy.log($el[0])
    expect($el).to.have.text('measure')
    expect($el[0]).to.have.text('measure')
})
```

Comment: yes `.should(chainers, value)` can work, but I need some extra assertion that can only achievable by `.should(callbackFn)`.

Comment: Ok I understand. Then I believe it would be better to use `then`. I've updated my comment to provide an exemple

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I found that when my test page includes `zepto`, such as `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.2.0/zepto.min.js"></script>`, then the test would fail.

Comment: Oh, I see. Might be a conflic between jQuery, Cypress jQuery, and the zepto wrapper around jQuery